# Why do websites have "member since October 20 2015" on their ecommerce website?

Tags: ux-field

Why do most websites have "member since date" in their profile page? What good does it serve? I understand it will determine how long the user has been using the website. But aside from that what else? Personalization? Remind users how long they have been using it?

I see this a lot on ecommerce and forums too.

Comment: Shot in the dark but if a user sees it it may make them feel more loyal and buy something. But the more likely reason is an ambitious dev that loves data and felt like putting it on there "because he can".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Membership is about belonging

You're asking about something deep and wide—connection, belonging, and community. If you want to understand the effect of "Member since …" statement, you have a bit of reading to do. Or you can skip to the last paragraph of this answer.

[image]
**Belonging** affects people in seemingly illogical ways, as [Susan Weinschenk writes in her blog](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/brain-wise/201310/people-who-are-connected-together-work-harder-0). If you want something more academic than a blog to read, [start with this](http://gageparkhs.enschool.org/ourpages/auto/2011/5/7/37616703/Sense%20of%20Community-McMillan%20and%20Chavis.pdf). **Membership** is one of the four elements of [sense of community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense_of_community), according to [David McMillan](http://www.drdavidmcmillan.com/category/community/) and David Chavis. **Sense of community** is tied to [self-identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(social_science)), according to [Seymour Sarason](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/02/08/education/08sarason.html). If you're looking at an eCommerce site, there's an additional connection between [self-identity and consumerism](http://www.academia.edu/2428249/Consumerism_and_Identity_Some_Psychoanalytic_Considerations) that you can explore.

The statement "Member since …" is a way to reinforce connection (where the user might not have felt it as much) or belonging, and is a subtle way to say "Welcome back" that can unobstrusively be repeated frequently or seldomly.

Answer (score -3):

My only guess is that it may be valuable if the site offers some sort of benefit/gift/reminder on a signup anniversary. Something along the lines of "you've been a valued customer for [x] years, here's a coupon for 20% off your next order!"

With regard to forums, the registration date may directly correlate with a seniority (implied or otherwise) of the group membership.